# How do I bring up an earlier version of my project and/or solution in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I know this is a simple question.  But I do not think it is easy to find this answer online.  For anyone who has used TFS (Team Foundation Server) on a Microsoft Visual Studio this must be the first thing they learn.  But I have poked around with Visual Studio and TFS and I do not find the solution intuitive.  Here is the question:

How do I bring up an earlier version of my project and/or solution in TFS?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Source Control window and right click on the folder at the root of your project you should see "Get Specific" or "Source Control | Get Specific". If you select this you will be presented with a dialog box that will ask you which version you want to get. This can be bases on Date, Lables, or changesets.